# Different coordinate systems match in QGIS but not in ArcGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have digitized some shapefiles (polygons) in QGIS. Some polygons have the CRS 5678 DHDN 3-Degree Gauss Kruger Zone 4 E-N and the rest have the CRS 4326 WGS84.
The Project coordinate system is also 5678 DHDN 3-Degree Gauss Kruger Zone 4 E-N.

But I don't know why they match on the map.

[image: QGIS]

Then I load the shapefiles into ArcGIS and because of the different coordinate systems they don't match there. I have tried anything (project, transform, reproject) and Google can't help me but I need the shapefiles to match in ArcGIS.

[image: ArcGIS]

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Do you have automatic reprojection on QGIS?

Comment: Automatic reprojection ("On-the-fly-reprojection") is set by default in QGIS if you have layers with different CRS. I suspect that Arcgis needs the proper DHDN to WGS84 datum shift.